# C++ - constantly increment an integer

Tags: c++, increment

I'm looking for a way to have an integer be constantly incremented every 10 seconds or so. I know how to get the integer to increment, but I don't know how to get it to continue to increment no matter what else is currently occurring in the rest of the program.

Comment: You are searching for something like will increment an integer after 10s in a thread independed of the main program execution

Comment: Can you not accomplish the same on demand arithmetically by storing a start time and comparing to the current time?

Comment: You can use a separate thread. Just let it loop for "every 10 seconds or so", let it sleep for 10 seconds between each increment. But why do you want this, what are you going to use the value for?

Comment: Initilize a `base = getCurrentMillis` at beginning. Whenever you want to access this integer, use `(getCurrentMillis - base) / (10 * 1000)` instead. Look for documentation to find `getCurrentMillis`

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::thread` for this.

Create a function

```
void incrementThread(int &i)
{
  while(someCondition)
  {
    //sleep for 10 seconds
    //increment your value
    i++;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int>(10));
  }
}
```

Now from `main`:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  std::thread t(incrementThread, std::ref(i));
  t.detach() // or t.join()
}
```

Comment: This would increment a local copy of `i` stored in `incrementThread`, `i` in `main` won't change.

Comment: make `i` static to fix this (I think)

Comment: This is not thread save. `i` has to be locked or `atomic<int>`. Otherwise read/write access from different threads is a data race and undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using *C++11* style:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> i{0};
    std::thread thread_time([&]() { while (true) { ++i; std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10)); } });
    while (true) {
        std::cout << i.load() << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    }
    thread_time.join();
    return 0;
}
```